# Status fields: ALTER TYPE vs. INSERT INTO?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, join, enum

I have a simple table with a status column:

```
create type status as enum (
  'approved',
  'pending_approval',
  'rejected'
);

create table document (
  id          serial primary key,
  uuid        uuid unique not null default uuid_generate_v4(),
  title       text not null,
  content     text,
  status      status not null,
  created_at  timestamptz not null default now(),
  updated_at  timestamptz not null default now(),
  deleted_at  timestamptz
);
```

This is the beginning of a small workflow-esque application I'm doing. Statuses, however, can be defined by the users of the application. What are the cons of using ALTER TYPE instead of creating a new table and using JOIN? I really don't want to add a JOIN to my queries just because of a status field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the cons of using ALTER TYPE instead of creating a new table and using JOIN? I really don't want to add a JOIN to my queries just because of a status field.

This is your typical pro/con enum vs normalization question.

## `ENUM` type

- Great if the range is fixed or only requires modification by the DBA.
- Get a really nice query syntax which optimized well (bottom assumes status is an ENUM)

  ```
  SELECT * FROM foo WHERE status = 'INVALID';
  ```
- Sorts well and permits easy range within the type. All enums are sorted and have ordinality
- Store in an 4 byte-size
- Can eliminate a JOIN
- PostgreSQL has ENUM types, not macros (like MySQL). This means you don't take a hit in maintenance. If you have five tables using your `ENUM` type you can still manage just that one type and not five tables.

## Normalized / `JOIN` method

- **Always** preferred if the user needs to be able to modify the domain/data
- **Always** preferred if the domain/data needs to shrink (remove values)
- Will provide easier modification with an ORM
- More traditional
- Can be smaller than `ENUM` (for instance `smallint` is two bytes, `enum` is **always** four bytes).

Comment: But why is it always preferred if the user needs to be able to modify the data? Why can't the application run the ALTER TYPE command?

Comment: @vinnylinux: If the app has the necessary privileges, it *can* run `ALTER TYPE`. But that would be risky business. `ALTER TYPE ... ADD VALUE` cannot run inside a transaction block. So it cannot be rolled back. And it cannot be wrapped in a server-side function. So its power is not easily contained. And you cannot remove a value from an enum type without tricks. Etc. In short: don't go there.